# ¿Como obtener registros repetidos en mysql?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo esta tabla

```
+------+----------------+-----------------+
| id   | home_team_name | visit_team_name |
+------+----------------+-----------------+
| 1436 | Philadelphia   | Miami           |
| 1431 | Jacksonville   | Carolina        |
| 1426 | Detroit        | New England     |
| 1461 | Tennessee      | Chicago         |
| 1371 | Tennessee      | Chicago         |
| 1366 | Washington     | Cincinnati      |
| 1456 | Washington     | Cincinnati      |
| 1441 | Minnesota      | San Francisco   |
| 1361 | Minnesota      | San Francisco   |
+------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Quisiera saber como hacer una consulta para que me muestre los duplicados, que serian:

```
+------+----------------+-----------------+
| id   | home_team_name | visit_team_name |
+------+----------------+-----------------+
| 1461 | Tennessee      | Chicago         |
| 1371 | Tennessee      | Chicago         |
| 1366 | Washington     | Cincinnati      |
| 1456 | Washington     | Cincinnati      |
| 1441 | Minnesota      | San Francisco   |
| 1361 | Minnesota      | San Francisco   |
+------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra forma, sería:

```
select  t1.id,
    t1.home_team_name,
    t1.visit_team_name 
    from tu_tabla t1
    inner join ( select     home_team_name,
                visit_team_name 
            from tu_tabla
            group by home_team_name,
                visit_team_name 
            having count(1) > 1
    ) t2
    on t1.home_team_name = t2.home_team_name
    and t1.visit_team_name = t2.visit_team_name
```

La subconsulta solo recupera aquellos casos donde se repita `home_team_name` y `visit_team_name` por medio del `group by` y el `having count(1) > 1`

Comment: gracias esto me ayudo mucho, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas buscar aquellos registros donde exista otro con los mismo datos, pero diferente `id`.
Para ello se puede crear una sub-consulta junto a [`EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT M.*
FROM matchs AS M
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM matchs
    WHERE home_team_name = M.home_team_name
        AND  visit_team_name = M.visit_team_name
        AND id != M.id
    LIMIT 1)
```

<kbd>[`Demo`](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=0f95764fe22761b50eb8dbe6d84416ff)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Primero debe obtener el listado de casos repetidos, para posteriormente listar cada uno de ellos

Por ejemplo :

```
select id, home_team_name, visit_team_name
from mytable 
where home_team_name in (
    select home_team_name
    from mytable 
    group by  home_team_name
    having count(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ver cuáles tienen duplicados la query sería:

```
SELECT * FROM mitabla 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT home_team_name FROM mitabla GROUP BY home_team_name, visit_team_name HAVING COUNT(*)>1) sel
ON mitabla.home_team_name = sel.home_team_name
```

Necesitas ver los registros dentro de aquellos que están duplicados para los campos que te interesen, los cuales se recogen en el select del paréntesis.